# 2012 Mac Mini not displaying in 1920x1200 on a 27" IPS Display

Tags: mac-mini

When I plug one display in to the Thunderbolt port I get 2560x1440 and it looks sweet.

Before I purchased another display I wanted to make sure the Mac Mini would display at 1920x1200 via the **included HDMI to DVI adapter**. But I can't get this to display at that resolution just 1920x1080.

I discussed this with a couple of Mac Genius guys at the Apple store. They didn't think it would do this resolution so I took them to the Apple page that says it will do this resolution via HDMI on the Mini. They suggested that I bring in my Mini and display into the store.

Just wondering do you have to have two displays before OS X displays one monitor at 1920x1200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac Mini can do 1920x1200 but it is probably the HDMI to DVI adapter doing the limiting.  The Mac will only display the resolutions that it is being told it supports by the connected device.

If you are trying to get the display to 1080p HDTV, it is doing it properly (HDTV is 1920x1080).

If you are trying to get to 1920x1200 for a different monitor with a DVI connector, it probably won't be able to, again due to the limit of the adapter.

The monitor can probably do the 1920x1200 but it can't communicate that to the Mac because the adapter is in the way, which is saying it can only do 1920x1080.

By chance does your display have other connection options, like DisplayPort or MiniDisplayPort?  You can get an HDMI to Display Port adapter which will allow the display and Mac to communicate properly.

Comment: Although it might not happen with HDMI to DisplayPort, I had a problem when doing a similar conversion.  Mine was from MiniDisplayPort (MacBookPro) to full sized DisplayPort (Dell 27" monitor).  I bought a single cable that had the proper connector on each end. Problem was that it ended up being a DisplayPort spec that didn't allow for that kind of converter in a cable.  I ended up buying a MiniDP to DP adapter then using a normal DP cable.  I would recommend the same here with something like [this adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=4826) and a normal HDMI cable.

Comment: I plan to pick one up in the morning. Thanks again.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a 2012 mac-mini and am getting 1920x1200 via the HDMI->DVI adapter. That IS my monitor's native resolution (it's a Dell U2412M).